# I want to display dates in imagepicker within a range, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to display dates in `UIImagePicker` within a range, I have start date and I will select start date and end date should automatically appear for a week, dates from past one week should appear. **i.e** if start date is 10 and end date should be displayed as 3 and dates should be Populated between 10 to 3 which should be displayed in iOS.

Comment: Please try to enhance presentation of your post

Comment: you want UIDatePicker not UIImagePicker!

Answer (score -1):

just use the `maximumDate` and `minimumDate` properties of UIDatePicker